# Who actually won Battle of the Hydaspes?

Tags: india, alexander-the-great

> The battle resulted in a Greek victory and the surrender of Porus.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Hydaspes) says Alexander won the battle.

> Porus’ defeat of Alexander at the Battle of Hydaspes (Jhelum) – N.S.
> Rajaram

But [voice of India](https://voiceofindia.me/2016/10/05/porus-defeat-of-alexander-at-the-battle-of-hydaspes-jhelum-n-s-rajaram/) says Porus won the battle in the title.

Who actually won Battle of the Hydaspes?

Comment: For context, and for anyone unfamiliar with VOI, it's perhaps worth looking at the Wikipedia page for [Voice of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_of_India), and the references listed there.  "*Voice of India (VOI) is a publishing house based in New Delhi, India, that specialises in Hindu nationalist books and serves as one of the most important tools in the development of Hindutva ideologies. It was established by Sita Ram Goel in 1981, to develop a Hindu triumphalist ideology, and has since published numerous authors subscribing to similar thought-schools*."

Comment: Maybe this should be a question, but are there any written sources for this battle that aren't Greek?

Comment: @T.E.D. It is indeed [a question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/14940/24858).  :-)

Comment: The article in VOI is just one more example of the [saffronisation of Indian history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saffronisation).  In case anyone is actually interested, the article [Did King Porus Defeat Alexander the Great?](https://talesoftimesforgotten.com/2019/11/17/did-king-porus-defeat-alexander-the-great/) ,by Spencer Alexander McDaniel, provides a fairly comprehensive de-bunking of the nationalist rewriting of this particular facet of Indian history.

Comment: Ah yes. Well then, while there might be some reason to be a bit skeptical about the Greek sources, we don't really have anything else to go by, do we? So anyone claiming anything wildly divergent from them is literally making stuff up.